# Unable to start MySQL Server

Tags: mysql

I tried to install MySQL on my Ubuntu server. But when I check the status using the command `systemctl status mysql`, I get

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-02-18 14:38:40 IST; 8min ago
  Process: 26867 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 13107 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 18 14:38:37 Ubuntu18 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Feb 18 14:38:37 Ubuntu18 mysqld[26867]: Initialization of mysqld failed: 0
Feb 18 14:38:37 Ubuntu18 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 18 14:38:40 Ubuntu18 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 18 14:38:40 Ubuntu18 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
root@Ubuntu18:/home/digith# systemctl start mysql.service
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When I run the command `systemctl restart mysql`, the output was,

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: Have you checked the output of "journalctl -xe" or "systemctl status mysql.service"?

Comment: yes I checked...

Comment: Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Feb 18 16:32:04 Ubuntu18 mysqld[21418]: Initialization of mysqld failed: 0
Feb 18 16:32:04 Ubuntu18 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 18 16:32:06 Ubuntu18 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 18 16:32:06 Ubuntu18 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed.

Comment: Did you initialize the server? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization.html

Comment: I followed this video but again failed to start mysql. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gt_7d7DL-78